# What is the meaning of "say" in the given sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across the following sentence:

> In practice, you might want to reduce data from 256 to 50 dimensions, **say**; but using lower [...]

If I rearranged the sentence to:

> In practice, you might want to reduce data from 256 to, **say**, 50 dimensions; but using lower [...]

Would that still mean the same thing? If not, what is the meaning of *say* in the first quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Say' used like that means 'for example' or 'approximately'. You could imagine it as a shortened form of "let us say" or "let's say". Your rearrangement works fine and does not change the meaning.

> Definition of say (Entry 3 of 3)
>   1: ABOUT, APPROXIMATELY
>   the property is worth, say, four million dollars
>
> 2: for example : AS
>   if we compress any gas, say oxygen

[Say (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/say)